# Problems uploading base64 images to server by httpPost

Tags: android, json, heap-memory, android-image

I am prototyping an application where I send the whole content of the local SQLite database to a remote MySQL database using JSON and HttpPost.

Everything works fine for text data. 
Now I added images to the party and I though I could add the images as base64 strings to the JSON I am sending away. My images are 800 x 600 pixels, more or less 500kb in size each.

If I paste the JSON generated by my app manually to a web page, it is fine, I get my images and everything else.

Using the app uploading script, I tried to upload a JSON string with 4 images but the application gets stuck at my progress dialog and Logcat goes on over and over showing this:

```
11-15 14:32:27.809: I/dalvikvm-heap(15562): Grow heap (frag case) to 21.964MB for 2680048-byte allocation
11-15 14:32:27.840: D/dalvikvm(15562): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1744K, 30% free 20666K/29447K, paused 2ms+3ms
11-15 14:32:27.879: D/dalvikvm(15562): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4362K, 39% free 18049K/29447K, paused 16ms
11-15 14:32:27.918: D/dalvikvm(15562): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 33% free 19794K/29447K, paused 22ms
11-15 14:32:27.918: I/dalvikvm-heap(15562): Grow heap (frag case) to 21.964MB for 2680276-byte    allocation
11-15 14:32:27.958: D/dalvikvm(15562): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1744K, 30% free 20667K/29447K, paused 1ms+4ms
11-15 14:32:27.997: D/dalvikvm(15562): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4362K, 39% free 18049K/29447K, paused 17ms
11-15 14:32:28.028: D/dalvikvm(15562): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 33% free 19795K/29447K, paused 17ms
```

and it goes on forever. I bet the images are too big to be sent this way, and/or I am leaking memory somewhere.

What would be a better approach to upload big size images along with JSON data to a server? Otherwise, how can I avoid memory leaks?

The code is pretty standard...

From Cursor to JSON:

```
private JSONObject get_images_data_JSON(Cursor c) {

    JSONObject image_jo = new JSONObject();

    //get unit identifier
    long unit_identifier = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));

    //set unit details
    try {

        image_jo.put("_id", unit_identifier);
        image_jo.put("unit_id", c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("unit_id")));

        //encode blob in Base64 for json parsing
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("image")), Base64.DEFAULT);

        image_jo.put("image", encodedImage);
        image_jo.put("caption", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("caption")));


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return image_jo;

}//end get_images_data_JSON
```

and the POST function:

```
public String postData(JSONArray array) {

    String responseMessage = "";

    //set connection timeout values
    HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();

    //set timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);

    //set timeout for waiting data
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 10000);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);

    //Get a string out of the JSONArray
    String json = array.toString();

    try {

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        httppost.setEntity(se);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        responseMessage = inputStreamToString(inputStream);

        //log out response from server
        longInfo(responseMessage);

    }
    //show error if connection not working
    catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        responseMessage = "unreachable";

    }

    catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        responseMessage = "unreachable";

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        responseMessage = "unreachable";

    }



    return responseMessage;

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: you should consider multipart. that's much more appropriate for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution just loads all the data to be sent into memory. That's hardly scalable. Consider using a multipart entity instead.

```
File image1;
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("json", new StringBody(serializedJson, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
entity.addPart("image1", new FileBody(image1, "application/octet-stream");
```

This example shows the case when i'm about to send a file available on the disk. By creating your own imlementation for AbstractContentBody, you should be able to send something located in your db, without consuming too much memory...

Comment: If you have the images as files, that's just perfect. If they are stored in the database (as your example suggests), you might need to subclass of FileBody... Or you can write the blobs from db into files, as a quick hack, and include them as FileBody...

Comment: I might change my app logic and have the image as files on the device, that is not a big deal. But what about sending multiple images with data like "title" and "description" associated with them? A typical scenario would be uploading 50/60 images on a single http request.

Comment: Each entity has a name in the request. Add a number or id to each parameter... like title_1, description_1, image_1...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here, I solved all the problems following Vajk advice and this is my new POST function:

```
public String postData(Cursor images, JSONArray json_array) {

    int counter = 0;
    String responseMessage = "";

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

        //convert JSON array to String
        String json_encoded_string = json_array.toString();

        //MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

        //add json data
        entity.addPart("json", new StringBody(json_encoded_string));

        //get all images plus data and add them to the Multipart Entity

        for (images_cursor.moveToFirst(); !images_cursor.isAfterLast(); images_cursor.moveToNext()) {

            counter++;

            //Get image as byte array
            byte[] image_ba = images_cursor.getBlob(images_cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
            long image_unit_id = images_cursor.getLong(images_cursor.getColumnIndex("unit_id"));
            String image_caption = images_cursor.getString(images_cursor.getColumnIndex("caption"));

            //add image to multipart
            entity.addPart("image" + counter, new ByteArrayBody(image_ba, "image" + counter + ".jpg"));

            //add unit _id to multipart
            entity.addPart("image_unit_id" + counter, new StringBody(String.valueOf(image_unit_id)));

            //add caption to multipart
            entity.addPart("image_caption" + counter, new StringBody(String.valueOf(image_caption)));

        }

        httppost.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        responseMessage = inputStreamToString(inputStream);

        //log out response from server
        longInfo(responseMessage);

    }
    //show error if connection not working
    catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        responseMessage = "unreachable";

    }

    catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        responseMessage = "unreachable";

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        responseMessage = "unreachable";

    }

    return responseMessage;
}
```

Someone might find this useful ;)